# What is a 7 letter preposition that has a and w? NOT TOWARDS

Tags: single-word-requests, prepositions

I am doing something, which requires me to know a 7 letter preposition containing the letters A and W. It is not towards, sadly. Can I get some help? I toured the internet tying to find it. It would be nice to get an answer ASAP

Thanks,
Ali

(Here is the actual text: The actual answer is the seven-letter preposition containing the letters A and W.)

Comment: You really need some more details, whether meaning or letter pattern.

Comment: yeah. I know. Thats all I got

Comment: Is the answer given in your question from a crossword puzzle? Maybe you could post a picture of the puzzle with all the relevant clues visible.

Comment: guessing words is on topic?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because crosswords are off-topic.

Comment: Hello, Ali. As @tchrist says, we are not a word-game and crossword-puzzle site; we're a site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English-language enthusiasts. This question is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple words that fit this description (which I found using the OED, most of which are obsolete):

- athwart (["From side to side of; across."](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/athwart))
- a-weather (["on or toward the weather or windward side "](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aweather))
- froward (["Away from."](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/froward#Preposition)—obsolete/archaic)
- halfway ("Half-way up, down, along, etc."—definition from OED, obsolete)
- himward ("towards him"—definition from OED, probably obsolete)
- midward ("In the middle of"—definition from OED, obsolete)
- onwards ("On, over; along."—definition from OED, obsolete)
- tilward ("In the direction of, toward."—definition from OED, obsolete)
- towards (mentioned in the question)
- upwards ("Up along the course of"—definition from OED, obsolete)

Comment: Great list. Surprised by all the "obsolete" words there - I still use "upward" and "onward" (although no "s" in my use). Can’t be "amidward" because that’s 8 letters.

Comment: @Pam Do you use it as a *preposition*? Some of these words have non-preposition uses that are not obsolete, but I only looked at the preposition sense. (BTW, amidward has been removed.)

Comment: No, you’re right, I’d be much more likely to say "Onward, to the boss fight!", so not preposition usage.

Answer (score 0):

**Athwart**, meaning according to [Oxford Dictionaries Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/athwart):

> "From side to side of; across."

**Froward**, [link to Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/froward), [link to Wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/froward#Preposition)

#### Attribution

[1](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/athwart) "Athwart | Definition of athwart in English by Oxford Dictionaries." Oxford Dictionaries | English. Accessed March 24, 2018. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/athwart.

Comment: Thank you, but... Apparently wrong! Maybe I understood the question wrong...?

Comment: @AliMosallaei can you state the full question (or a picture of the question) in your opening post?

Comment: @AliMosallaei added another one, not at all common but it fits your description.

Comment: How do you know it’s wrong? (What other info do you have?)